# Usage of と in 明日は来られないと先生に伝えてください

Tags: grammar

1. Is this mean, if you don't come tomorrow, please tell the teacher ?
2. Can we use なら instead of と
3. Is there any imply that when should they tell the teacher, such as if they plan to not come tomorrow then tell the teacher today or if you decide tomorrow that you don't come then tell the teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ***quotative*** 「と」.

> 明日は来られない**と**先生に伝えてください。
>
> ≒
>
> 『明日は来られない。』**と**先生に伝えてください。

= "***Please tell the teacher that I/you/someone will not be able to come tomorrow***."

From this sentence alone, we could not tell who it is that will not be able to come.  Further context would reveal it.

> 1.Is this mean, if you don't come tomorrow, please tell the teacher ?

No, it does not.  「と」 does not mean "if" here.

> 2.Can we use なら instead of と?

No, we cannot because someone already ***knows*** that he will not be able to come tomorrow.  If 「なら」 is used, the meaning of the sentence will change.

> 3.Is there any imply that when should they tell the teacher, such as if they plan to not come tomorrow then tell the teacher today or if you decide tomorrow that you don't come then tell the teacher?

Good question.  In this sentence by itself, there is no implying as to when someone should tell the teacher.

All we know for sure is that someone will not be able to come tomorrow.  It is not that he will decide tomorrow whether he will come or not tomorrow.